# Basic Quantile Calculation

Tags: statistics, quantile

I have a slight confusion with the current method of calculation of a quantile for a give ungrouped distribution. To give you an example, i shall refer to calculation of a Quartile, but this doubt applies to any quantile.

Let's take a distribution as follows:

0,2,4,9,10

n=5

The formulae to calculate the lower quartile and upper quartile are as follows:

Q1=(n+1)/4

Q3=3*(n+1)/4

So as per these formulae, the upper and lower quartile should appear at positions 1.5 and 4.5

We can all agree here that the median of the distribution is 4 (i.e., position 3)

However, to derive the upper and lower quartile values, we have to assume that the end point values of the range are 0 and 10 (i.e, position 1 and 5). Hence by this logic, and assuming the end point values of the range are 0 and 10 (position 1 and 5) and the median as 4 (position 3), we should get the upper and lower quartile positions as 2 (i.e. (1+3)/2) and 4 (i.e. (5+3)/2) respectively.

However, going by the accepted formula we see that we see that the lower quartile 1.5 is a median position between a non-existant position 0 and 3, and the upper quartile 4.5 is a median position between position 3 and a non-existant position 6.

Can anyone please clarify why the non-existant positions are assumed? Perhaps I'm looking at it from a wrong angle, so please let me know.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile: "For discrete distributions, there is no universal agreement on selecting the quartile values."

Comment: Thank you for that. It appears that my doubt was with Method 1, and i tried to explain how method 2 would be more appropiate.

Comment: Roughly speaking, quartiles separate the $n$ _sorted_ observations into four 'chunks' of about $n/4$ observations each. There are about half a dozen formulas for quartiles, depending on text or software, each with its own method of dealing with $n$ not divisible by 4, tied values, etc. The default method in R statistical software with `x = c(0,2,4,9,10)` uses `quantile(x)` (where quartiles are the default), to give $Q_1=2, Q_3=9,$ and median $4.$ (Differences among methods are of little consequence for large $n,$ for which the concept of quartile has its main practical uses.)

Comment: Worth also considering the nine methods described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample